# Force the input language of Chrome's address bar to default to English

Tags: windows, google-chrome, language

I often switch between two input languages while I'm browsing depending on the context of what I'm doing. However, when I go to the address bar, 99% of the time, I want to type something in English but I end up accidentally typing in the other language very frequently, which is pretty annoying.

So, I'm wondering if there's a way to force the input language of the address bar to always default to English unless I explicitly switch the language while the cursor is in the address bar.

Is this possible to achieve? Perhaps using Chrome flags, a browser extension, etc.

Comment: How do you enter the address bar - click or shortcut ?

Comment: @harrymc Both. Sometimes, I use the mouse, other times, I use the F6 shortcut, but I think most of the time, it happens when I open a new tab (Ctrl+T) or a new window (Ctrl+N). In both cases, the address bar gets the focus automatically.

Comment: I was also annoyed and tried to write my own Chrome Extension for it, but seems like that's not what a Chrome Extension can do. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free and open-source
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will start chrome with the required argument
`--force-renderer-accessibility` and will change the Windows keyboard
layout when the focus changes to the address bar of Chrome.

As a requirement, download from Github and unpack the library
[UIAutomation](https://github.com/Descolada/UIAutomation/tree/main)
into a folder.
You will need to modify in the script the folder for
`UIAutomation\Lib` and the path to `chrome.exe`.

Note that you can remove from the script the `Run` command for Chrome,
and just leave the script to run : It will work on any Chrome instance
that is started with the `--force-renderer-accessibility` argument,
so you could just add this argument to your Chrome invocation.
You may also want to navigate to `chrome://accessibility/` and
enable the `Internal` option. For more about accessibility see
the Chromium article
[Accessibility Overview](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/accessibility/overview.md).

Here is the script :

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1.33+
#SingleInstance, force
#Warn
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetBatchLines, -1

; --- MODIFY these three lines as needed ---
#include C:\Temp\UIAutomation-main\Lib\UIA_Interface.ahk
#include C:\Temp\UIAutomation-main\Lib\UIA_Browser.ahk
browserExe := "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Run, %browserExe% --force-renderer-accessibility
WinWaitActive, ahk_exe %browserExe%
cUIA := new UIA_Browser("ahk_exe " browserExe)
h := UIA_CreateEventHandler("EventHandler", "FocusChanged") ; Create a new FocusChanged event handler that calls the function EventHandler
cUIA.AddFocusChangedEventHandler(h) ; Add a new FocusChangedEventHandler
OnExit("ExitFunc") ; Set up an OnExit call to clean up the handler when exiting the script
return

EventHandler(el) {
    global cUIA
    try {
        if cUIA.CompareElements(cUIA.URLEditElement, el) ; Check if the focused element is the same as Chrome's address bar element
            SetDefaultKeyboard(0x0409) ; english-US - If the Address bar was focused set languagse
    }
}

ExitFunc() {
    global cUIA, h
    cUIA.RemoveFocusChangedEventHandler(h) ; Remove the event handler. Alternatively use cUIA.RemoveAllEventHandlers() to remove all handlers
}

; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values?view=windows-11
SetDefaultKeyboard(LocaleID){
    Global
    SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG := 0x005A
    SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE := 2
    Lan := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", Format("{:08x}", LocaleID), "Int", 0)
    VarSetCapacity(Lan%LocaleID%, 4, 0)
    NumPut(LocaleID, Lan%LocaleID%)
    DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", "UInt", SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG, "UInt", 0, "UPtr", &Lan%LocaleID%, "UInt", SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)
    WinGet, windows, List
    Loop %windows% {
        PostMessage 0x50, 0, %Lan%, , % "ahk_id " windows%A_Index%
    }
}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: Yeah, I know a little bit about AutoHotKey. I was making some attempts of my own and my search led me to the UIAutomation library just before I saw your answer, but it would've taken me a long time to go through the docs and figure out how to use it correctly. So, thanks a lot for this save. I'll probably modify the code a little bit so it stores the current LocaleId on focus and reverts to it when the address bar loses focus, but this is a perfect start for me. Thanks again!